# Custom events cant change TextBlock text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have a class which has simple event, but when the event occurs,  subscribed method which should change TextBlock.Text accordingly to event parameter does nothing. I have no idea why this is happening? It is propably very simple thing, but I couldn't have found the answer.

```
<!-- this is the event of my WordHelper class -->
public delegate void WordHelperHandler(string attempt);
public event WordHelperHandler WordParsed;

<!-- this is excerpt from MainPage class -->
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        helper = new WordHelper();
        helper.WordParsed += SetText;
        helper.Load(); //this method calls the event
    }
public void SetText(string text)
    {
        PageTitle.Text = text;
    }
```

Comment: Well is the `WordParsed` event ever being raised by the helper?

Comment: Yes, of Course, I wrote it in the code comment, I followed code in debugger and it is executed, but nothing happens

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in the `SetText` method? Events really *do* work - but seeing only such a small portion of your code, it's hard to help you. (A short but *complete* program would be much easier to help you with.)

Comment: In load method there is a very long loop, and I have found out, that only when the load method ends, the text is changed (I breaked loop after first iteration). So, is there a way to force event to have an effect exectly when it is invoked?

Comment: Ah, that's a completely different matter. Yes, you need another thread.

Comment: You mean, that I should execute Load method in another thread? eg using asynchronous delegate? Could you explain it more precisely? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your code is basically doing a lot of work on the UI thread. That doesn't let the UI respond until you've completed.

Instead, you should run the background task in a different thread . Then in your event handler, you'll need to use the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) to get back to the UI thread in order to update the textbox:

```
public void SetText(string text)
{
    Action action = () => PageTitle.Text = text;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
}
```